# Side chapter thumb headings conflicts with part sectioning

Tags: sectioning, scrlayer-scrpage, chapterthumb

This is a modification of [Koma-script / Anhang-B](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/info/examples/KOMA-Script-3/Anhang-B/) that separates chapters into parts. How would I disable this feature where a new part starts? In the example given, this means removing thumb "Chapitre 2" from page "Deuxième partie:Bar".

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script-examples/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\part{Foo}

\chapter{Pas du tout}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Un peu}

\lipsum[2]

\pagestyle{empty}
\part{Bar}

\chapter{Beaucoup}

\lipsum[3]

\chapter{Passionnément}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Off topic: remove `\pagestyle{empty}` before `\part{Bar}`. It changes the page style of the normal (where no chapter or part starts) pages to empty. And it changes the page style of the page before part »Bar« starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from `\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}`. It adds layer `chapterthumb` to style `@everystyle@`. Therefore the chapterthumbs are used with all layer page styles: `empty`, `scrheadings`, `plain` (alias of `plain.scrheadings`), ...

You can define a new page style for the part pages and add `chapterthumbs` only to page styles `scrheadigs` and `plain.scrheadings`:

```latex
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}% http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/KOMA-Script-6/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb.sty
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{part}{}
\renewcommand\partpagestyle{plain.part}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{chapterthumb}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{chapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\part{Foo}
\chapter{Pas du tout}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Un peu}
\lipsum[2]

\part{Bar}
\chapter{Beaucoup}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{Passionnément}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or you can remove layer `chapterthumb` from `@everystyle@` on part pages:

```latex
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}% http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/KOMA-Script-6/Anhang-B/source/chapterthumb.sty
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}

\newcommand*{\oldpartheadendvskip}{}
\let\oldpartheadendvskip\partheadendvskip
\renewcommand\partheadendvskip{%
  \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}%
  \oldpartheadendvskip
  \AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\part{Foo}
\chapter{Pas du tout}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Un peu}
\lipsum[2]

\part{Bar}
\chapter{Beaucoup}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{Passionnément}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```