# Why does the Chapterthumb example gives errors?

Tags: koma-script, chapterthumb

I am using texlive/scrbook for a large book. Using chapterthumb as shown in the koma-script book 3rd edition in Appendix B

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test1}
test1
\chapter{test2}
\end{document}
```

gives the following errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \undefinedpagestyle 
                               
l.10 \pagestyle{scrheadings}
                            

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \lohead
            [\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
   

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Do you know what is wrong? What did I miss that changed from koma-script version 3.00 to 3.38 of the current version in texlive? The fact that the chapterthumb.sty was in the doc tree is a minor issue.

Comment: I get a different error: ! LaTeX Error: File `chapterthumb.sty' not found. CTAN does not know that package name either

Comment: You have to put the chapterthumb.sty from the doc-tree into somewhere where it is found following texhash.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but I think the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509773/ is applicable to your situation as well.

Comment: You are correct. I got the answer already from M. Kohm via email before I have seen your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the seventh edition of Komascript there have been some changes in line 4 and 5. The correct test would be now.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb} in 
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{test1}
    test1
    \chapter{test2}
    test2
\end{document}
```